# run linux cat command in python or bash loop

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

i have 999,999 files in a directory:

```
member.php\?1

member.php\?2

...

member.php\?99999
```

I want to run the below `cat` commands in bash or python loop on specific files.  This command is supposed to extract usernames from .php files, but doesn't work because of the large number of files involved.

```
root@alimp5: cat member.php\?* | grep -i '<li class="navbit lastnavbit"><span>' | cut -d'>' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1  >> users.txt
```

My solution (this way works fine): execute above cat command step by step on each file as follows:

```
root@alimp5:cat member.php\?1* | grep -i '<li class="navbit lastnavbit"><span>' | cut -d'>' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1  >> users.txt

root@alimp5:cat member.php\?2* | grep -i '<li class="navbit lastnavbit"><span>' | cut -d'>' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1  >> users.txt

...

root@alimp5:cat member.php\?9* | grep -i '<li class="navbit lastnavbit"><span>' | cut -d'>' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1  >> users.txt
```

I want to automate the above solution by running it in a python loop or a bash loop.

For example (doesn't work):

```
import os, sys

for count in range(1,10):
  os.system('''cat member.php\?%d* | grep -i '<li class="navbit lastnavbit"><span>' | cut -d'>' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1  >> users.txt''') %count
```

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your python command, you are doing it wrongly , the `% count` should be inside the `os.system()` call. Example -

```
os.system('''cat member.php\?%d* | grep -i '<li class="navbit lastnavbit"><span>' | cut -d'>' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1  >> users.txt''' % count)
```

Also, you should iterate till the amount you want.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1...9999999}
do
   $i 
done
```

Now you just add the $i next to the command you pretend

```
'cat member.php\?$i
```

Comment: This would work for the exact number, but isn't it better to pipe the output of `ls` or `find`?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, I would use `glob` to scan the directory, in case the number of file changes.

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('member*'):
   process(file)
```

where process is your function dealing with the file given as an argument.

Also, notice that if your php file is actually filled with HTML, you could use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to get the work done.

In bash, I would use `find`:

```
find . -name member\*; -exec sh -c "grep -i '<li class=\"navbit lastnavbit\"><span>' | cut -d'>' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1  >> users.txt"
```

or simply

```
for file in member*; do 
  grep -i '<li class=\"navbit lastnavbit\"><span>' ${file} | cut -d'>' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1  >> users.txt
done
```